# collecting a list sent from the backend in angular

Tags: angular, list

So I have a Customer and Vehicle class in the backend. They are mapped with each other as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    //... getter and settors
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vehicle")
public class Vehicle {
    
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String vin;
    private String warrantyPeriod;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
 
    //...getters and settors
}
```

I have created entries in the database as follows

Customer :
[image]

Vehicle :
[image]

Now, when I try to fetch the value of *warrantyPeriod* from a vehicle in the customer object in the angular front end in the ngOnInit() as follows

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    
    this.customerService.getCustomer(this.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.customer = data;
      }, error => console.log(error));
      console.log(this.customer.vehicles[0].warrantyPeriod);
  }
```

it gives an error saying
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
The customerService is set up properly to fetch the values from the backend and prints the proper values for name, email and address, it only has a problem with the list object. Can someone explain me how I can collect the values of the list object in the front end? The Customer object in angular is declared as follows in customer.ts file

```
import { Vehicle } from './vehicle';
export class Customer{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    address: string;
    vehicles: Vehicle[];
}
```

P.S : `console.log(this.customer.vehicles.length);` gives the same error. Also I checked the frontend, it's sending all the data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is that you tried to access an undefiend variable. Try to put your bussiness logic into the subscribe method since the http is asncy all the rest code  which is after the request is executed before getting back your response from the backend.

```
 this.customerService.getCustomer(this.id)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.customer = data;
    console.log(this.customer.vehicles[0].warrantyPeriod); // Moved the console.log here
  }, error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: check in the console what is in the customer property.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['customer_id']'
In your frontend

Comment: That's what I'm using to get the id.